# How to works javascript codes at every domain in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp library. When I first open WebBrowser, I can catch any javascript event on the browser side, but when I go to another address I can't add the boundEvent event again and I get a javascript error on the console side: Cannot read property 'raiseEvent' of undefined.

C# code:

```
public void InitCefBrowser(string url)
{
    CefSharpSettings.FocusedNodeChangedEnabled = true;
    CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;

    CefBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
    {

        BrowserSettings =
                    {
                        DefaultEncoding = "UTF-8"
                    },
        JsDialogHandler = new JsDialogHandler(),


        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    };

    Panel1.Controls.Add(CefBrowser );
    CefBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;

    eventObject = new ScriptedMethodsBoundObject();
    eventObject.EventArrived += OnJavascriptEventArrived;
    CefBrowser.RegisterJsObject("boundEvent", eventObject, options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
}

private void OnJavascriptEventArrived(string eventName, object eventData)
{
        var jsonString = eventData.ToString();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dataDict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

        switch (eventName)
        {
            case "click":
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                    {
                        if (dataDict["Path"] != null)
                            TextBox1.Text = dataDict["Path"].ToString();
                    }));

                    break;
                }
        }
}


private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    string scripts = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\javascript\events.js", Encoding.UTF8);
    CefBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(scripts);

    try
    {
        CefBrowser.ShowDevTools();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

}

private void BtnGoToPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CefBrowser.Load(TxtUrl.Text);
}
```

Javascript Result Code:

```
window.boundEvent.raiseEvent("click", "Test");
```

This code working on one domain. I want it's to work in every domain.

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled.htm

Comment: You need to use the newer binding method described in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/2febd683b9e9f08e19aab68b575bae8b349c0ba5 for a working example